How can I generate a running total of a time series with start and end dates?
I have data with start and end dates for each row (including some NAs) and I want to generate a time series with a running total of how many have been started and how many have ended.
Sample data
data.frame(
  name = c("building a", "building b", "building c", "building d", "building e"),
  start = as.Date(c("2011-04-09", "2011-12-30", "2012-11-10", "2015-06-05", "2017-03-12")),
  end = as.Date(c("2016-05-04", NA, "2015-01-19", NA, "2019-04-06"))
)
#>          name      start        end
#> 1  building a 2011-04-09 2016-05-04
#> 2  building b 2011-12-30       <NA>
#> 3  building c 2012-11-10 2015-01-19
#> 4  building d 2015-06-05       <NA>
#> 5  building e 2017-03-12 2019-04-06

What's a good way to get this proposed output?
#>         date started ended
#> 1 2011-04-09       1     0
#> 2 2011-12-30       2     0
#> 3 2012-11-10       3     0
#> 4 2015-01-19       3     1
#> 5 2015-06-05       4     1
#> 6 2016-05-04       4     2
#> 7 2017-03-12       5     2
#> 8 2019-04-06       5     3

I will be plotting the started and ended columns as cumulative line charts so I'm open to any intermediate data structure, this is just my initial thought about how it would look. For example, this question is similar:
Cumulative sum that updates between two date ranges. The final part of the accepted answer uses an id column and count column instead of started and ended columns. That might make it easier to plot, grouping by id.

The key is to pivot into long format, arrange by date, and conditionally count the start and end entries:
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c("building a", "building b", "building c", "building d", "building e"),
  start = as.Date(c("2011-04-09", "2011-12-30", "2012-11-10", 
                    "2015-06-05", "2017-03-12")),
  end = as.Date(c("2016-05-04", NA, "2015-01-19", NA, "2019-04-06"))) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(start, end), names_to = "event", values_to = "date") %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  filter(!is.na(date)) %>%
  mutate(started = cumsum(ifelse(event == "start", 1, 0)),
         ended = cumsum(ifelse(event == "end", 1, 0))) %>%
  select(date, started, ended)

This gives the desired output:
df
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   date       started ended
#>   <date>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2011-04-09       1     0
#> 2 2011-12-30       2     0
#> 3 2012-11-10       3     0
#> 4 2015-01-19       3     1
#> 5 2015-06-05       4     1
#> 6 2016-05-04       4     2
#> 7 2017-03-12       5     2
#> 8 2019-04-06       5     3

To plot this, I would also pivot this result into long format, so you have one column for counts, and another labelling those counts as belonging to either the started or ended series.
df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(started, ended), names_to = "event", values_to = "count") %>%
  mutate(event = factor(event, c("started", "ended"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, count, colour = event)) +
  geom_step(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(started = "green4", ended = "red2")) +
  theme_bw(20)


